# How to type sentences into Mathematica

Tags: formatting, text

I am writing a paper and in conjunction with the paper I want to submit a Mathematica file that shows the numerical calculations.  But I want it to follow in order of the paper.  I know this is probably a silly and easy question.  How do I enter text without using the Text command?  In other words, how do I get the use Mathematica as, say, a word document in which I can then input commands after?  Sorry for the basic question but I don't get it.

Comment: You can select a cell and do [Format > Style > Text](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/Style.html) (keyboard shortcut Alt+7). Also, in the current version, you should see [a popup](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RnSlG.png) prompting you to convert your cell into a text cell when you start typing something that looks like a sentence.

Comment: Thanks!  That should take care of it.

Comment: @J.M. basic but useful - answer?

Comment: @Yves, prolly later; I'm running something at the moment. (But if you'd like to write one on my behalf... ;))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(J.M.'s comment)

You can select a cell and do **Format** > **Style** > **Text**,

[image: menu item]

or you can directly right-click on a cell bracket,

[image: right-clicking]

or you can convert or generate a new text cell by the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.

Also, in version 10, you should see a popup prompting you to convert your cell into a text cell when you start typing something that looks like a sentence, even in an input cell:
[image: popup]

Comment: Thanks @István for the initial write-up! I've added screenshots for further illustration.

Comment: @J.M. You're welcome.

Comment: This was awesome! Thanks